# is structure of code causing undefined $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php

When I navigate to a page which is locked (in other words when the box which states you have to `Continue` appears, I am getting undefined `$_SESSION` variables. Before I included the `if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed"){` statement, I was not getting any undefined $_SESSION variables but as  now need that if statement, Im starting to get those variable errors.

For the `$_SESSION` undefined errors, is it because I am placing the $_SESSION variables in the wrong place?

Below is an example `QandATable.php` order of code looks like:

```
        <?php

        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
        ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
        ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
        ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
        require_once 'init.php'; 
        //12 hours sessions

        session_start();
        include('steps.php'); //exteranlised steps.php

?>
        <head>

<?php
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

        $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

        }


        if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
                    //Declare my counter for the first time

                    $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
                    $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
                    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;

            }

        elseif (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
            $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
        }
?>

        </head>

        <body>

        <?php 

    //once session is expired, it should log the user out, but at mo this isn't happening
        if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){ //checks if user is logged in

            if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed"){

        //QandATable.php code:

        }else{

        $page = allowed_in()+1;


        ?>

        <div class="boxed">
          <a href="<?php echo $steps[$page] ?>">Continue with Current Assessment</a>

        <?php   

        }

        }else{ 

        echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>"; 
        //show above echo if user is not logged in

        }

        ?>
```

Below is the full steps.php:

```
<?php

$steps = array(1 =>'create_session.php',2 => 'QandATable.php',3 => 'individualmarks.php',4 => 'penalty.php',5 => 'penaltymarks',6 => 'complete.php');

function allowed_in($steps = array()){
// Track $latestStep in either a session variable
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = 0;
}
$currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx == 1 )
    {
       $currentIdx = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
       return 'Allowed';
    }
    return $latestIdx;
}

?>
```

Comment: why are those `ini_set()`s not in your php.ini or .htaccess file? Using `ini_set()` in code is intended for settings that you want to change dynamically; not those you want to be set that way every time php runs.

Comment: you have a stray `<head>` in the middle of the PHP code. That will cause a syntax error the way you've got it.

Comment: Your live will be a lot easier when you indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

session_start() must go before any content.

> Note:
>
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php